# Tap-able areas on a pdf in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, pdf

There is a job that I will soon have to start that requires certain areas of a pdf (pictures within the pdf) to be tap-able and play a sound when tapped.

Now I understand that I could get the rect/coordinates of each tap zone and check the touch or place a button over the tap zone and play the sound that way, but that just seems a horribly ugly way to do it and I would have to store the 'tap zone data' for each pdf, the number of which is currently unknown, but could be 100's or more!

Is there a more elegant solution or workaround?? What would you do?

Not looking for code, just ideas.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking for ideas, I recommend a PDF library that solves all of these issues so you can focus on the unique parts of your apps. I'm the author of PSPDFKit so I'm biased, but you can google - there are a few options out there (though all of them are commercial).

In our product, we expose a simple way to get the coordinates of text and images:

https://pspdfkit.com/api/ios/Classes/PSPDFDocument.html#//api/name/objectsAtPDFRect:page:options:

That will give you [`PSPDFImageInfo`](https://pspdfkit.com/api/ios/Classes/PSPDFImageInfo.html) objects.

You can implement the default delegate for tapping:
https://pspdfkit.com/api/ios/Protocols/PSPDFViewControllerDelegate.html#//api/name/pdfViewController:didTapOnPageView:atPoint:

And then do a hit test for image and call your custom code.